# Sql - IN Clause with case selection statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select the list of records from Table A where the Id's present in Table B or C. My query is like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A 
          WHERE  ID IN (
                  CASE WHEN (SOME CONDITION )
                          THEN
                                 SELECT _ID FROM TABLE_B
                           ELSE 
                                 SELECT _ID FROM TANLE_C
                    END )
```

But what am getting  is only one record .the first record i am getting.
Can anyone helpme. please

Comment: I have a hard time believing this wouldn't just throw an error

Comment: Can you provide sample data and results?

Answer (score 1):

Hm, that's tricky. Usually I don't like `CASE` expressions in the `WHERE` clause, but in order not to have to repeat <some condition>:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a 
WHERE CASE WHEN <some condition>
        THEN ID IN (SELECT _id FROM table_b)
        ELSE ID IN (SELECT _id FROM table_c)
      END
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
select . . .
from table_a a
where (<some condition> and
       exists (select 1 from table_b b where b._id = a.id
      ) or
      (not <some condition> and
       exists (select 1 from table_c c where c._id = a.id
      )
```

This assumes that `<some condition>` is not `NULL`.  If so, then the logic would need to be tweaked.

Comment: If `<some condition>` can result in null, you'd have to extend this to `(not <some condition> or <some condition> is null)` or `coalesce(not <some condition>, false)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this without having to use the CASE WHEN clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_A 
WHERE  
(<SOME CONDITION> AND ID IN (SELECT _ID FROM TABLE_B))
OR 
(<SOME CONDITION> AND ID IN (SELECT _ID FROM TABLE_C))
```